# How to get rid of duplicates in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Note: I know we use Set to get rid of duplicates in array.

I have a date dropdown.When I choose a date, it shows the date correctly in a list.

But the issue is if I select a already selected date,it too shows in the list.
I want that if a user selects a already selected date,it should not add in the list and instead show an error 'You cannot choose the same date'.

Here is the code-->

```
                 <Col md={12}>
                     <Datetime
                        timeFormat={false}
                        dateFormat={dateFormate}
                        // onChange={this.handleStartDate}
                        onBlur={this.handleStartDate}
                        onFocus={this.onFocus}
                      />
                   </Col>
                        {dateDay.map((dateday, dateDayindex) => (
                          <Col md={1} className="p-t-6">
                           {dateday.date}
                          </Col>
)}
```

//handleStartDate

```
handleStartDate = (date) => {
    const { dateDay } = this.state;
    const selectedDate = moment(date).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
    this.setState(
      {
        isSelectedDate: true,
      },
      () => {
        this.addDate(selectedDate);
      },
    );
  };
addDate = (selectedDate) => {
    const { dateDay } = this.state;
    const obj = { wday: '', interval: [], date: selectedDate, type: 'date' };

    const newInterval = { from: '9:00am', to: '10:00am', error: null };
    obj.interval.push(newInterval);
    arr.push(obj);
    if (arr.length > 1) {
      const isOverlaped = this.checkTimeOverlap(arr, arr.length - 1);
      if (isOverlaped) {
        newInterval.error = 'Time overlap with another set of times';
      }
      if (selectedDate === 'Invalid date') {
        newInterval.error = 'Please select a valid date';
      }
    }
    this.setState({ dateDay: arr });
```

Comment: can you create a codesandbox or codepen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a validation inside your handleStartDate that checks if the selected date is already in the dateDay state:

```js
handleStartDate = (date) => {
    const { dateDay } = this.state;
    const selectedDate = moment(date).format('DD/MM/YYYY');

    // If selectedDate doesn't exist on the dateDay state, add it. Otherwise, show alert message
    if (!dateDay.find(obj => obj.date === selectedDate)) {
        this.setState(
            {
                isSelectedDate: true,
            },
            () => {
                this.addDate(selectedDate);
            },
        );
    } else {
        alert('You cannot choose the same date')
    }
};
```